# storing output of echo in a variable

Tags: shell, sh

I am using echo and sed to print a string between two strings, but it is giving me error "no such file of directory"

```
$SEARCH_1=12  
$FO_FILE=myfile.txt

SEARCH=$(head -$SEARCH_1 $FO_FILE | tail -1 | grep BShare)  
LOC=echo $SEARCH_2 | sed 's/\(.*\)BShare>\(.*\)<\/BShare\(.*\)/\2/g'
```

If I don't use LOC= and use only echo it prints the string correctly.
example

```
<test>mystring</test> will be printed as mystring
```

but if I assign the echo command to a variable it says "no such file or directory"

Comment: what is SEARCH_2? no value is assigned to it, how can it give correct result?

Comment: Don't use the dollar sign when you **assign** a variable: `search_1=12; fo_file=myfile.txt`. I strongly recommend you don't use ALL_CAPS_VARNAMES, save those for the shell's use -- one day you'll write `PATH=5` and wonder why your script is broken.

Comment: Why do you think there is a difference between the assignment to `SEARCH` (where you use `$(...)`) and to `LOC` (where you do not)?

Answer (score 2):

To capture the output of a command and assign it to a variable you need to use backticks or `$( ... )`, e.g.

```
LOC=`echo $SEARCH_2 | sed 's/\(.*\)BShare>\(.*\)<\/BShare\(.*\)/\2/g'`
```

or

```
LOC=$(echo $SEARCH_2 | sed 's/\(.*\)BShare>\(.*\)<\/BShare\(.*\)/\2/g')
```

---

The problem with the original command

```
LOC=echo $SEARCH_2 | sed 's/\(.*\)BShare>\(.*\)<\/BShare\(.*\)/\2/g'
```

is that the shell here tries to run what ever `$SEARCH_2` evaluates to (with a environmental variable LOC set to value echo), and pipe the output of that to sed.

Comment: Don't recommend backticks. `$(...)` is easier to read (IMO) and far easier to nest.